# ImageResizingModule not run for static content despite runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"

Tags: image-resizing, imageresizer, imageresizer-diskcache

I'm trying to use ImageResizer (v4) to handle all image requests but I can only get the images from database (using plugin SqlReader) to work.  Plain images in the images folder (or other folders) are not handled for some reason. I'm testing with very simple querystrings like /images/x.png?width=50 . Here is my output from resizer.debug.ashx:

```
    Image resizer diagnostic sheet      localhost   5/19/2017 6:47:51 PM

2 Issues detected:

resizer configuration(ConfigurationError):  You have specified default commands (format) that will cause all image requests to be proccessed; even those that do not need ImageResizer.
            <pipeline defaultCommands="fastscale=true&amp;format=jpg&amp;quality=70" />


resizer configuration(Error):   No license found for domain localhost - features installed: R4Performance or R4DiskCache AND R4Performance or R4BlobProviders


Assembly use report: 


You are using plugins and assemblies from the V4 Performance Edition.


----------------

License keys

You do not have any license keys installed.

----------------



Registered plugins:

ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.DefaultEncoder
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.NoCache
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.ClientCache
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.Diagnostic
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.WebConfigLicenseReader
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.SizeLimiting
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.MvcRoutingShimPlugin
ImageResizer.Plugins.DiskCache.DiskCache
ImageResizer.Plugins.LicenseVerifier.LicenseEnforcer`1[ImageResizer.Plugins.DiskCache.DiskCache]
ImageResizer.Plugins.PrettyGifs.PrettyGifs
ImageResizer.Plugins.FastScaling.FastScalingPlugin
ImageResizer.Plugins.SqlReader.SqlReaderPlugin
ImageResizer.Plugins.LicenseVerifier.LicenseEnforcer`1[ImageResizer.Storage.BlobProviderBase]

Configuration:

<resizer>
<pipeline defaultCommands="fastscale=true&amp;format=jpg&amp;quality=70" />
<plugins>
<add name="DiskCache" />
<add name="PrettyGifs" />
<add name="FastScaling" />
<add name="SqlReader" prefix="~/img/" connectionString="[redacted]" idType="Int" blobQuery="SELECT Content FROM Images WHERE Id=@id" modifiedQuery="Select ModifiedDate, CreatedDate From Images WHERE ImageID=@id" existsQuery="Select COUNT(Id) From Images WHERE Id=@id" requireImageExtension="false" cacheUnmodifiedFiles="true" extensionPartOfId="false" checkForModifiedFiles="false" vpp="false" untrustedData="false" />
</plugins>
<diskcache dir="~/imgcache" />
</resizer>


Accepted querystring keys:

quality, format, thumbnail, colors, dither, f.sharpen, maxwidth, maxheight, width, height, w, h, crop, page, bgcolor, rotate, flip, sourceFlip, sFlip, sRotate, borderWidth, borderColor, paddingWidth, paddingColor, frame, useresizingpipeline, cache, process, margin, dpi, zoom, autorotate, 

Accepted file extensions:

bmp, gif, exif, png, tif, tiff, tff, jpg, jpeg, jpe, jif, jfif, jfi, 

Environment information:

Running Microsoft-IIS/10.0 on Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.14393.0 and CLR 4.0.30319.42000
Trust level: Unrestricted
OS bitness: AMD64
Executing assembly: c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
IntegratedPipeline: True

Installed HttpModules: 

System.Web.Caching.OutputCacheModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a          (under keyOutputCache)
System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a          (under keySession)
System.Web.Security.WindowsAuthenticationModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a          (under keyWindowsAuthentication)
System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a          (under keyFormsAuthentication)
System.Web.Security.DefaultAuthenticationModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a          (under keyDefaultAuthentication)
System.Web.Security.RoleManagerModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a          (under keyRoleManager)
System.Web.Security.UrlAuthorizationModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a          (under keyUrlAuthorization)
System.Web.Security.FileAuthorizationModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a          (under keyFileAuthorization)
System.Web.Security.AnonymousIdentificationModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a          (under keyAnonymousIdentification)
System.Web.Profile.ProfileModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a          (under keyProfile)
System.Web.UrlMappingsModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a          (under keyUrlMappingsModule)
System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a          (under keyUrlRoutingModule-4.0)
System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35          (under keyScriptModule-4.0)
System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHttpModule, System.ServiceModel.Activation, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35          (under keyServiceModel-4.0)
WebMarkupMin.AspNet4.HttpModules.HtmlMinificationModule, WebMarkupMin.AspNet4.HttpModules, Version=2.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=99472178d266584b          (under keyHtmlMinificationModule)
WebMarkupMin.AspNet4.HttpModules.HttpCompressionModule, WebMarkupMin.AspNet4.HttpModules, Version=2.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=99472178d266584b          (under keyHttpCompressionModule)
ImageResizer.InterceptModule, ImageResizer, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null          (under keyImageResizingModule)
Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.PerWebRequestLifestyleModule, Castle.Windsor, Version=3.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=407dd0808d44fbdc          (under key__DynamicModule_Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.PerWebRequestLifestyleModule, Castle.Windsor, Version=3.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=407dd0808d44fbdc_0a4ced7a-d68e-4945-b47e-ef41e2dc2533)
Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpModule, Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35          (under key__DynamicModule_Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpModule, Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35_9c96216b-f685-42cd-b2a0-5fbfa2688d4d)
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime.Tracing.PageInspectorHttpModule, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a          (under key__DynamicModule_Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime.Tracing.PageInspectorHttpModule, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a_79b40b26-e637-4036-ba3d-07748d5bfa5c)
System.Web.WebPages.WebPageHttpModule, System.Web.WebPages, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35          (under key__DynamicModule_System.Web.WebPages.WebPageHttpModule, System.Web.WebPages, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35_89c621b1-fb8d-4270-b829-b5d1100f62f5)
System.Web.Optimization.BundleModule, System.Web.Optimization, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35          (under key__DynamicModule_System.Web.Optimization.BundleModule, System.Web.Optimization, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35_1fa38abb-8524-4007-9f72-26b331e783cc)

Loaded assemblies:

mscorlib                                 Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1648.0      Info: 4.6.1648.0
System.Web                               Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1637.0      Info: 4.6.1637.0
System                                   Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1647.0      Info: 4.6.1647.0
System.Core                              Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1647.0      Info: 4.6.1647.0
System.Configuration                     Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1586.0      Info: 4.6.1586.0
System.Xml                               Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1586.0      Info: 4.6.1586.0
System.Web.ApplicationServices           Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1637.0      Info: 4.6.1637.0
System.Runtime.Caching                   Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1637.0      Info: 4.6.1637.0
Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0           Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1586.0      Info: 4.6.1586.0
System.Web.RegularExpressions            Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1586.0      Info: 4.6.1586.0
Microsoft.JScript                        Assembly: 10.0.0.0        File: 14.6.1586.0     Info: 14.6.1586.0
System.Web.WebPages.Razor                Assembly: 3.0.0.0         File: 3.0.30128.0     Info: 3.0.3-30128 (0e974218e12a67d4b1f25422119e40cfe6953e46)
Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb            Assembly: 3.1.0.0         File: 3.1.60405.82    Info: 3.1.0
System.Web.Optimization                  Assembly: 1.1.0.0         File: 1.1.40211.0    
System.Web.Mvc                           Assembly: 5.2.3.0         File: 5.2.30128.0     Info: 5.2.3-30128 (0e974218e12a67d4b1f25422119e40cfe6953e46)
Castle.Windsor                           Assembly: 3.4.0.0         File: 3.4.0.91        Info: 3.4.0.91
System.Web.WebPages.Deployment           Assembly: 3.0.0.0         File: 3.0.30128.0     Info: 3.0.3-30128 (0e974218e12a67d4b1f25422119e40cfe6953e46)
System.Web.WebPages                      Assembly: 3.0.0.0         File: 3.0.30128.0     Info: 3.0.3-30128 (0e974218e12a67d4b1f25422119e40cfe6953e46)
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Loader Assembly: 1.0.0.0         File: 14.1.21111.0    Info: 14.1.21111.0.K-1.0.1.b65
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime Assembly: 14.0.0.0        File: 14.1.21111.0    Info: 14.1.21111.0.K-1.0.1.b65
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Tracing Assembly: 14.0.0.0        File: 14.1.21111.0    Info: 14.1.21111.0.K-1.0.1.b65
System.Runtime.Serialization             Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1637.0      Info: 4.6.1637.0
SMDiagnostics                            Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1637.0      Info: 4.6.1637.0
System.ServiceModel.Internals            Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1637.0      Info: 4.6.1637.0
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.HtmlParser Assembly: 14.0.0.0        File: 14.1.21111.0    Info: 14.1.21111.0.K-1.0.1.b65
Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure             Assembly: 1.0.0.0         File: 1.0.20105.407  
App_global.asax.dqpxun8g                 Assembly: 0.0.0.0        
Gentide.Web                              Assembly: 1.0.0.0         File: 1.0.0.0        
Abp.Web                                  Assembly: 2.0.0.0         File: 2.0.0.0         Info: 2.0.0
Abp                                      Assembly: 2.0.0.0         File: 2.0.0.0         Info: 2.0.0
System.Web.Extensions                    Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1637.0      Info: 4.6.1637.0
System.ServiceModel.Activation           Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1586.0      Info: 4.6.1586.0
System.ServiceModel                      Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1637.0      Info: 4.6.1637.0
System.Xaml.Hosting                      Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1586.0      Info: 4.6.1586.0
WebMarkupMin.AspNet4.HttpModules         Assembly: 2.4.0.0         File: 2.4.0.0        
WebMarkupMin.AspNet4.Common              Assembly: 2.4.0.0         File: 2.4.0.0        
WebMarkupMin.AspNet.Common               Assembly: 2.4.0.0         File: 2.4.0.0         Info: 2.4.0
WebMarkupMin.Core                        Assembly: 2.4.0.0         File: 2.4.0.0         Info: 2.4.0
Microsoft.CSharp                         Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1586.0      Info: 4.6.1586.0
System.Data                              Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1636.0      Info: 4.6.1636.0
System.Web.Services                      Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1586.0      Info: 4.6.1586.0
System.Drawing                           Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1586.0      Info: 4.6.1586.0
System.EnterpriseServices                Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1586.0      Info: 4.6.1586.0
System.IdentityModel                     Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1637.0      Info: 4.6.1637.0
System.ServiceModel.Web                  Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1586.0      Info: 4.6.1586.0
System.Activities                        Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1637.0      Info: 4.6.1637.0
System.ServiceModel.Activities           Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1586.0      Info: 4.6.1586.0
System.WorkflowServices                  Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1586.0      Info: 4.6.1586.0
System.Data.DataSetExtensions            Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1586.0      Info: 4.6.1586.0
System.Xml.Linq                          Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1586.0      Info: 4.6.1586.0
System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations    Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1586.0      Info: 4.6.1586.0
System.Web.DynamicData                   Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1586.0      Info: 4.6.1586.0
Abp.AutoMapper                           Assembly: 2.0.0.0         File: 2.0.0.0         Info: 2.0.0
Abp.Castle.Log4Net                       Assembly: 2.0.0.0         File: 2.0.0.0         Info: 2.0.0
Abp.EntityFramework.Common               Assembly: 2.0.0.0         File: 2.0.0.0         Info: 2.0.0
Abp.EntityFramework                      Assembly: 2.0.0.0         File: 2.0.0.0         Info: 2.0.0
Abp.HangFire                             Assembly: 2.0.0.0         File: 2.0.0.0         Info: 2.0.0
Abp.Owin                                 Assembly: 2.0.0.0         File: 2.0.0.0         Info: 2.0.0
Abp.Web.Api                              Assembly: 2.0.0.0         File: 2.0.0.0         Info: 2.0.0
Abp.Web.Common                           Assembly: 2.0.0.0         File: 2.0.0.0         Info: 2.0.0
Abp.Web.Mvc                              Assembly: 2.0.0.0         File: 2.0.0.0         Info: 2.0.0
Abp.Web.SignalR                          Assembly: 2.0.0.0         File: 2.0.0.0         Info: 2.0.0
Abp.Zero.Common                          Assembly: 2.0.0.0         File: 2.0.0.0         Info: 2.0.0
Abp.Zero                                 Assembly: 2.0.0.0         File: 2.0.0.0         Info: 2.0.0
Abp.Zero.EntityFramework                 Assembly: 2.0.0.0         File: 2.0.0.0         Info: 2.0.0
ACMESharp                                Assembly: 0.8.2.0         File: 0.8.2.0         Info: 0.8.2
ACMESharp.PKI.Providers.BouncyCastle     Assembly: 0.8.2.0         File: 0.8.2.0         Info: 0.8.2
AjaxMin                                  Assembly: 5.14.5506.26196
Antlr3.Runtime                           Assembly: 3.5.0.2         File: 3.5.0.2        
AutoMapper                               Assembly: 6.0.2.0         File: 6.0.2.0         Info: 6.0.2-master-8b260ff1
BouncyCastle.Crypto                      Assembly: 1.8.1.0         File: 1.8.15362.1     Info: 1.8.1
Castle.Core                              Assembly: 3.3.0.0         File: 3.3.0.43        Info: 3.3.0.43
Castle.Facilities.Logging                Assembly: 3.4.0.0         File: 3.4.0.91        Info: 3.4.0.91
Castle.Services.Logging.Log4netIntegration Assembly: 3.3.0.0         File: 3.3.3.58        Info: 3.3.3.58
EntityFramework                          Assembly: 6.0.0.0         File: 6.1.40302.0     Info: 6.1.3-40302
EntityFramework.DynamicFilters           Assembly: 2.6.0.0         File: 2.6.0           Info: 2.6.0
EntityFramework.SqlServer                Assembly: 6.0.0.0         File: 6.1.40302.0     Info: 6.1.3-40302
Gentide.Application                      Assembly: 1.0.0.0         File: 1.0.0.0        
Gentide.Core                             Assembly: 1.0.0.0         File: 1.0.0.0        
Gentide.EntityFramework                  Assembly: 1.0.0.0         File: 1.0.0.0        
Hangfire.Core                            Assembly: 1.6.12.0       
Hangfire.SqlServer                       Assembly: 1.6.12.0       
ImageResizer                             Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.5.942       Info: 4.0.5  Commit: 3d5572f812a7c9252402583ffbb006d08baa90f0
ImageResizer.Plugins.AnimatedGifs        Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.5.942       Info: 4.0.5  Commit: 3d5572f812a7c9252402583ffbb006d08baa90f0
ImageResizer.Plugins.DiskCache           Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.5.942       Info: 4.0.5  Commit: 3d5572f812a7c9252402583ffbb006d08baa90f0
ImageResizer.Plugins.FastScaling         Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.5.942       Info: 4.0.5  Commit: 3d5572f812a7c9252402583ffbb006d08baa90f0
ImageResizer.Plugins.PrettyGifs          Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.5.942       Info: 4.0.5  Commit: 3d5572f812a7c9252402583ffbb006d08baa90f0
ImageResizer.Plugins.SqlReader           Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.5.942       Info: 4.0.5  Commit: 3d5572f812a7c9252402583ffbb006d08baa90f0
ImageResizer.Storage                     Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.5.942       Info: 4.0.5  Commit: 3d5572f812a7c9252402583ffbb006d08baa90f0
Imazen.Profiling                         Assembly: 1.0.0.0         File: 1.0.0.0        
Imazen.WebP                              Assembly: 9.0.1.0         File: 9.0.1          
JetBrains.Annotations                    Assembly: 10.4.0.0        File: 10.4.0.0        Info: 10.3.0
log4net                                  Assembly: 2.0.8.0         File: 2.0.8.0         Info: 2.0.8.0-.NET 4.5
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core           Assembly: 2.0.0.0         File: 2.2.1.40403.0  
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework Assembly: 2.0.0.0         File: 2.2.1.40403.0  
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin           Assembly: 2.0.0.0         File: 2.2.1.40403.0  
Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core            Assembly: 2.2.1.0         File: 2.2.50714.868   Info: 2.2.1
Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SystemWeb       Assembly: 2.2.1.0         File: 2.2.50714.868   Info: 2.2.1
Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Core            Assembly: 2.0.0.0         File: 2.0.4.0         Info: 2.0.4
Microsoft.Data.Edm                       Assembly: 5.8.1.0         File: 5.8.1.62767     Info: 5.8.1.62767
Microsoft.Data.OData                     Assembly: 5.8.1.0         File: 5.8.1.62767     Info: 5.8.1.62767
Microsoft.Data.Services.Client           Assembly: 5.8.1.0         File: 5.8.1.62767     Info: 5.8.1.62767
Microsoft.Owin                           Assembly: 3.1.0.0         File: 3.1.60405.82    Info: 3.1.0
Microsoft.Owin.FileSystems               Assembly: 3.1.0.0         File: 3.1.60405.82    Info: 3.1.0
Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies          Assembly: 3.1.0.0         File: 3.1.60405.82    Info: 3.1.0
Microsoft.Owin.Security                  Assembly: 3.1.0.0         File: 3.1.60405.82    Info: 3.1.0
Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook         Assembly: 3.1.0.0         File: 3.1.60405.82    Info: 3.1.0
Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google           Assembly: 3.1.0.0         File: 3.1.60405.82    Info: 3.1.0
Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth            Assembly: 3.1.0.0         File: 3.1.60405.82    Info: 3.1.0
Microsoft.Owin.Security.Twitter          Assembly: 3.1.0.0         File: 3.1.60405.82    Info: 3.1.0
Microsoft.Owin.StaticFiles               Assembly: 3.1.0.0         File: 3.1.60405.82    Info: 3.1.0
Microsoft.Threading.Tasks                Assembly: 1.0.12.0        File: 1.0.168.0       Info: 1.0.168.0
Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.Desktop Assembly: 1.0.168.0       File: 1.0.168.0       Info: 1.0.168.0
Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.Extensions     Assembly: 1.0.12.0        File: 1.0.168.0       Info: 1.0.168.0
Microsoft.Web.Administration             Assembly: 7.0.0.0         File: 10.0.10011.16384
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics       Assembly: 2.8.0.0         File: 2.8.0.0        
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime    Assembly: 2.7.0.0         File: 2.7.1198.768    Info: 2.7.1198.768 (rd_art_stable.160418-1850)
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage           Assembly: 8.1.1.0         File: 8.1.1.0        
MonAgentListener                         Assembly: 33.1.0.0        File: 33.1.5.0       
Newtonsoft.Json                          Assembly: 10.0.0.0        File: 10.0.2.20802   
Nito.AsyncEx.Concurrent                  Assembly: 4.0.1.0         Info: 4.0.1
Nito.AsyncEx                             Assembly: 4.0.1.0         Info: 4.0.1
Nito.AsyncEx.Enlightenment               Assembly: 4.0.1.0         Info: 4.0.1
nQuant.Core                              Assembly: 1.0.3.0         File: 1.0.3          
Owin                                     Assembly: 1.0.0.0         File: 1.0            
PagedList                                Assembly: 1.17.0.0        File: 1.17           
PagedList.Mvc                            Assembly: 4.5.0.0         File: 4.5            
RestSharp                                Assembly: 105.2.3.0       File: 105.2.3.0       Info: 105.2.3
SimpleImpersonation                      Assembly: 2.0.1.27158     Info: 2.0.1
Stripe.net                               Assembly: 8.1.1.0         File: 8.1.1.0         Info: 8.1.1
System.Collections.Concurrent            Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1586.0      Info: 4.6.1586.0
System.Collections                       Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1586.0      Info: 4.6.1586.0
System.Collections.Immutable             Assembly: 1.2.1.0         File: 4.6.24816.01    Info: 4.6.24816.01. Commit Hash: 4d1af962ca0fede10beb01d197367c2f90e92c97
System.ComponentModel.Annotations        Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1586.0      Info: 4.6.1586.0
System.ComponentModel.EventBasedAsync    Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1586.0      Info: 4.6.1586.0
System.Diagnostics.Debug                 Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1586.0      Info: 4.6.1586.0
System.Diagnostics.Tracing               Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1586.0      Info: 4.6.1586.0
System.Dynamic.Runtime                   Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1586.0      Info: 4.6.1586.0
System.Globalization                     Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1586.0      Info: 4.6.1586.0
System.IO                                Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1586.0      Info: 4.6.1586.0
System.Linq.Dynamic.Core                 Assembly: 1.0.0.0         File: 1.0.0.0         Info: 1.0.6.13
System.Linq.Dynamic                      Assembly: 1.0.6132.35681 
System.Linq.Expressions                  Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1586.0      Info: 4.6.1586.0
System.Net.Http.Formatting               Assembly: 5.2.3.0         File: 5.2.30128.0     Info: 5.2.3-30128 (0e974218e12a67d4b1f25422119e40cfe6953e46)
System.Net.NetworkInformation            Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1586.0      Info: 4.6.1586.0
System.Net.Primitives                    Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1586.0      Info: 4.6.1586.0
System.Net.Requests                      Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1586.0      Info: 4.6.1586.0
System.ObjectModel                       Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1586.0      Info: 4.6.1586.0
System.Reflection                        Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1586.0      Info: 4.6.1586.0
System.Runtime                           Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1586.0      Info: 4.6.1586.0
System.Runtime.Extensions                Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1586.0      Info: 4.6.1586.0
System.Runtime.InteropServices           Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1586.0      Info: 4.6.1586.0
System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives  Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1586.0      Info: 4.6.1586.0
System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml         Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1586.0      Info: 4.6.1586.0
System.ServiceModel.Http                 Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1586.0      Info: 4.6.1586.0
System.Spatial                           Assembly: 5.8.1.0         File: 5.8.1.62767     Info: 5.8.1.62767
System.Text.Encoding                     Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1586.0      Info: 4.6.1586.0
System.Text.Encoding.Extensions          Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1586.0      Info: 4.6.1586.0
System.Text.RegularExpressions           Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1586.0      Info: 4.6.1586.0
System.Threading                         Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1586.0      Info: 4.6.1586.0
System.Threading.Tasks                   Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1586.0      Info: 4.6.1586.0
System.Web.Helpers                       Assembly: 3.0.0.0         File: 3.0.30128.0     Info: 3.0.3-30128 (0e974218e12a67d4b1f25422119e40cfe6953e46)
System.Web.Http                          Assembly: 5.2.3.0         File: 5.2.30128.0     Info: 5.2.3-30128 (0e974218e12a67d4b1f25422119e40cfe6953e46)
System.Web.Http.WebHost                  Assembly: 5.2.3.0         File: 5.2.30128.0     Info: 5.2.3-30128 (0e974218e12a67d4b1f25422119e40cfe6953e46)
System.Web.Razor                         Assembly: 3.0.0.0         File: 3.0.30128.0     Info: 3.0.3-30128 (0e974218e12a67d4b1f25422119e40cfe6953e46)
System.Xml.ReaderWriter                  Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1586.0      Info: 4.6.1586.0
System.Xml.XDocument                     Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1586.0      Info: 4.6.1586.0
System.Xml.XmlSerializer                 Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1586.0      Info: 4.6.1586.0
WebGrease                                Assembly: 1.6.5135.21930 
WebMarkupMin.MsAjax                      Assembly: 2.4.0.0         File: 2.4.0.0         Info: 2.4.0
System.Data.Linq                         Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1586.0      Info: 4.6.1586.0
Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly Assembly: 0.0.0.0        
System.Transactions                      Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1586.0      Info: 4.6.1586.0
System.Numerics                          Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1586.0      Info: 4.6.1586.0
System.Dynamic                           Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1586.0      Info: 4.6.1586.0
System.Net.Http                          Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1586.0      Info: 4.6.1586.0
DynamicProxyGenAssembly2                 Assembly: 0.0.0.0        
DynamicProxyGenAssembly2                 Assembly: 0.0.0.0        
System.Linq                              Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1586.0      Info: 4.6.1586.0
System.Resources.ResourceManager         Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1586.0      Info: 4.6.1586.0
System.Xaml                              Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1647.0      Info: 4.6.1647.0
System.Data.OracleClient                 Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1586.0      Info: 4.6.1586.0
EntityFrameworkDynamicProxies-Gentide.Core Assembly: 1.0.0.0        
EntityFrameworkDynamicProxies-Abp.Zero.Common Assembly: 1.0.0.0        
System.Web.Mobile                        Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.6.1586.0      Info: 4.6.1586.0
App_Web_gok4oxno                         Assembly: 0.0.0.0        
App_Web_zv3hty4a                         Assembly: 0.0.0.0        
App_Web_d2stohu5                         Assembly: 0.0.0.0        
App_Web_yi1kiijf                         Assembly: 0.0.0.0        
App_Web_ang5xqis                         Assembly: 0.0.0.0        
App_Web_nfj4qrsv                         Assembly: 0.0.0.0        

The following plugin assemblies are loaded but do not seem to be in use. You should remove them (and especially their dependencies (unless used elsewhere)) from the /bin folder to improve application load times:

ImageResizer.Plugins.AnimatedGifs        Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.5.942       Info: 4.0.5  Commit: 3d5572f812a7c9252402583ffbb006d08baa90f0
```

I don't have any routes that in any way interfere with either /img or any other image folder.

I'm using IIS 10 and the app pool is set to Integrated v4.0.

The module works great for database images. /img/1.jpg?width=50 works as expected.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using AspnetBoilerplate. After much trial and error I found that it was something in the OWIN integration in ABP that caused the Imageresizer module to not run in the case in question. As I'm not using the OWIN part of ABP I simply turned it off by removing this line:

Startup.cs:

```
app.UseAbp();
```